# delete users in power shell using a csv file (What I am missing?)

Tags: powershell, opencsv

Well now I am trying this

ForEach ($name in $list){  Get-CimInstance -ComputerName oa-exwit -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq $name } | Remove-CimInstance

> > 

but nothing happens, no errors no deleted user, nothing

Comment: Please use proper code insertion. 1.) You should change to `Import-CSV`. 2.) There's syntax errors literally everywhere in your code. 3.) After you import the csv, you reference the corresponding column by the header name using dot notation, `$list.names` (assuming you have a column with a header of "names"). This isn't WQL or Batch, you have to use appropriate variables in which `%var%` doesn't work.

Comment: 4.) If you're going to use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet, you have to pipe `|` to it. 5.) There's are removing the corresponding users on the local computer, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#"C:\Users\caro\script.ps1" command to run the script
#list is a variable array that connects to the computer and collects the profiles
#users is a variable array that collects the users to be deleted
#first loop interact the users array and ask that for each name do interact in the second loop that contains the profiles array;
#once the loop check if there is a coincidence between the first loop and second loop it deletes the instance

$list= Get-CimInstance -ComputerName oa-exwit -Class Win32_UserProfile
$users= Get-Content file.csv

ForEach($user in $users){

```
ForEach($name in $user){ 
        
    ForEach($profile in $list) {
        if ($name -eq $profile.LocalPath.split('\')[-1]){
        Remove-CimInstance($profile)
        }
    else{
    continue
    }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Theres Syntax errors everywhere. This will never work unless you correct the errors with the cmdlets displayed. For example: `GetContent` should be `Get-Content`. Cmdlets (Command Line utilities) in Powershell follow this "Verb-Noun" Structure and always use a hyphin "`-`". Get-Something, or Set-Something.

`Get-ChildItem` #enumerate through the current directory. You get the idea.

```
#Import the csv file
$list = Import-Csv -Path C:\my\location\file.csv 

#Assuming you have headers in your csv with one being names for the samaccount name.
#We can iterate through them using a Foreach loop.
    Foreach($name in $list.names){
    Get-CimInstance -ComputerName oa-exwit -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $name } | Remove-CimInstance}
```

Look into this Function to delete remote profiles (or local) to save you the work: [Delete Remote Profiles](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4857-delete-remote-user-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

Of try this...

```
Import-Csv -Path "$PWD\file.csv" | 
ForEach{
    Try
    {
        ((Get-CimInstance -ComputerName 'oa-exwit' -ClassName Win32_UserProfile).LocalPath -split('\\'))[-1] -eq $PSItem.SamAccountName | 
        Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf
    }
    Catch{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
```